# mapping non exist file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

if robots.txt non exist it mupping on robots.php, but if exist -return robots.txt

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{robots.txt} !-f [NC]
    RewriteRule robots.txt robots.php [L]
```

this code always return robots.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt/$ robots.php [L]
```

Think that's what you need...

Comment: This says the following: If the requested filename does not exist, apply the following rule. The following rule, in this case, says "if the requested URL is robots.txt, rewrite it to robots.php". It doesn't care if robots.txt exists or not.

Comment: but if %{REQUEST_FILENAME} exist why it rewrite it? but not get it from disk?